# understanding a qthread subclass's run method and thread context

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, concept

i have an encoder class with lots of methods . this is a subclass of  Qthread. i am new to multi-threading and

> trying to understand how this class is
>   threading its methods

... i understand to thread a method it has to be in a subclass of qthread. and the run of this implements the threaded code for this class. And the thread starts  only when a call to start method on the object of this class is made.

> *Question :*  firstly what do you infer
>   from the this run implementation

```
void Encoder::run(void)
{
    VERBOSE(VB_DEBUG, "Encoder::run");

    if (WILL_PRINT(VB_DEBUG))
        print_stats_timer_id = QObject::startTimer(kEncoderDebugInterval);
    health_check_timer_id = QObject::startTimer(kEncoderHealthCheckInterval);

    if (init())
        exec();
    else
        VERBOSE(VB_ERROR, "Encoder::run -- failed to initialize encoder");

    QObject::killTimer(health_check_timer_id);
    if (print_stats_timer_id)
        QObject::killTimer(print_stats_timer_id);

    cleanup();
}
```

> *Question:* what does thread context mean in
>   relation to its methods .

also

> *Question:* what would happen If a method of this
>   class is called before this class's
>   thread has started

Comment: it would really be helpful if the answers could be provided as per the questions asked in the above post rather than linking to some blog post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The class you have written creates a thread and initializes a QObject::timer. It then goes on to call a user defined init() function then the [QThread::exec()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html#exec) function.

   1. My guess is that you intended that exec() would be a user defined function where the actual work is to occur. Be aware that QThread::exec() processes the thread's Qt Event Queue.
   2. Also, on some platforms you may get an "Error creating timer from thread" warning message. I've encountered this error on Windows when the code executed fine on Linux
   3. Also, be aware that your timer will never occur if you do not call the QThread::exec() function or [QApplication::processEvents()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) from within your thread.
2. Thread context in Qt is the same as any other thread concept. That is, all memory is shared between the threaded code (entered at this point in your "run()" function). And any other context which calls into your object. If this object may ever be executing in a thread and accessed from outside of the thread you *must* protect the shared data.
3. Because all data is shared between thread contexts (it's a shared memory multiprocessing model) there is no problem with calling functions before/after/during thread execution. Given that:

   1. The object is fully constructed before you call any method. This is not special to threads, necessarily, unless the object is created in a thread.
   2. Any data member is protected with a mutex lock (I eluded to this in #2). [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmutexlocker.html) is a handy stack based RAII way of dealing with mutex locks in Qt.

I believe I fully answered your question here, so I'll go ahead and link to [RAII](http://blog.emptycrate.com/node/274) and [threading](http://blog.emptycrate.com/taxonomy/term/38) articles I have written on another site, just for further reference.

Edit: specificity about threading scenarios:

```
class MyThreadedClass : public QThread
{
  MyThreadClass(const boost::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass> &t_object)
    : m_object(t_object) {}

  void doSomething()
  {
    // Depending on how this method was called (from main, from internal thread)
    // will determine which thread this runs on, potentially complicating thread
    // safety issues.
    m_object->someThing(); 
  }

  void run()
  {
    // I'm now in a thread!
    m_object->someFunction(); // oops! The call to someFunction is occurring from 
                              // a thread, this means that SomeOtherClass must be 
                              // threadsafe with mutex guards around shared 
                              // (object level) data.
    // do some other stuff
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyThreadClass thread(someobjectfromsomewhere);
  thread.start(); // MyThreadClass is now running
  thread.doSomething(); // The call to doSomething occurs from main's thread.
                        // This means 2 threads are using "thread", main 
                        // and "thread"'s thread. 
  // The call to thread.doSomething hits Thread.m_object, which means that 
  // now multiple threads are also accessing m_object ("thread" and "main").
  // This can all get very messy very quickly. It's best to tightly control 
  // how many threads are hitting an object, and how
}
```

- *NOTE: It would be a good idea to investigate [QFuture](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuture.html), which is designed to handle this kind of asynchronous task, like an encoder, that you are looking at* QFuture will avoid some of the potential threading issues of shared data and deadlocks.

Comment: if i call a method of the encoder class from another class  that is not called or used in the run. will this method be threaded in the encoder class context even though its not present in the run. will this method be threaded at all?

Comment: I'll update my answer to address that aspect of the question.

Comment: very good example and explanation. my question has to do with the "thread.doSomething();"  is this method running in the main thread context or the mythread context.

Comment: It occurs from main's thread. But it's important to understand that "context" is a tricky word here since all memory is shared between the threads.